# bash scripting, run commands in all subfolders with selections

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I need to run this command

```
trjconv -s run.tpr -f run.xtc -pbc mol -ur compact -o unwrap
```

for all the sub-directories following the naming pattern of `us_0.0, us_-0.2, us_-0.4 ... us_-3.8`. The command will also ask me to make a selection once I run it, and the answer will also be 0. How exactly should I script this in bash?

Comment: So, just to clarify, when you say `for all subdirectories`, do you mean that you need to cd into all these directories and run the command while in each directory, or that you need to have the name of one of those directory on `stdin` for each run, or that you need to provide one of the directories as an argument each time?

Comment: yes, you will need to execute the command within that directory with all the run.tpr, run.xtc files. so you will need to cd into all the directories and run.

Comment: And, when you say “all subdirectories”, are you including subdirectories of subdirectories, as in `foo/us_17.42`? Oh, also, can both of the numbers have multiple digits, as in `us_1234.5678`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you mean you need to pass each directory into stdin:

```
convAll ()
{
  while read line
  do
    echo -e "$line\n0" | trjconv -s run.tpr -f run.xtc -pbc mol -ur compact -o unwrap
  done
}

ls | grep -E 'us_-?[0-9]\.[0-9]+' | convAll
# NOTE: There's probably an even shorter one-liner version of this that uses `xargs`, but
#       I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.
```

### If you mean you need to pass each directory as an additional argument:

```
ls | grep -E 'us_-?[0-9]\.[0-9]+' | tr '\n' '\0' | \
     xargs -0 -n 1 trjconv -s run.tpr -f run.xtc -pbc mol -ur compact -o unwrap
```

### If you mean you need to `cd` into each directory:

```
convAll ()
{
  while read line
  do
    (\
       cd "$line" && \
       trjconv -s run.tpr -f run.xtc -pbc mol -ur compact -o unwrap || \
       echo "Command failed for '$line'." >&2 \
    )
  done
}

ls | grep -E 'us_-?[0-9]\.[0-9]+' | convAll
```

Comment: The directories do not all start with 0, and unless there is a typo in the question, the directories may also have a hyphen in them. The grep statement should be `grep -E 'us_-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'`

Comment: @savanto You're right; I didn't notice the hyphen.